# NerdTree displays odd horizontal lines

Tags: neovim

I feel like this must be in my .rc somewhere, but I'm using a very similar setup to what I used on my previous laptop.
I can share my .rc files if needed.

In the first image there are no lines displayed when I move over to NT

[image: NerdTree without odd lines]

When I move the cursor up (and only up) I see these lines. They go away as a move down.
[image: NerdTree with odd lines]

Comment: Same here. Which MacOs are you running? What does `vim --version` return? how are you installing / loading nerdtree?

Comment: I'm running OS Montery and NVIM v0.6.1

I'm not sure what you mean by installing/loading. I used vim-plug to get the nerdtree plugin, if that helps. 

I also noticed that running nvim inside of a docker container displays this odd behavior everywhere, not just in NT. Not sure if that narrows anything down

Thanks for responding :)

Comment: I'm running homebrew-compiled VIM (Vi Improved 8.2) with the Vundle plugin manager in iTerm2 on MacOS Big Sur. My lines look exactly the same as your screenshot (with the color change too). I think it might be some MacOS specific font rendering issue.

Comment: Is the first screenshot taken on a different machine? Could you include your .rc file in an edit?

Comment: @DannyDannyDanny Both screenshots are of the same machine, seconds apart. I can throw the .rc up late, after work. Good looks on the font rendering hypothesis - I'll try late to see if changing fonts does anything.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Please have a look at [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) for when you [edit] in your vimrc